# Filtering results on page with Django and Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am working on a Django project where items are displayed on the main page. I am trying to get a filter working on this page so that if I check some checkboxes it will filter the results to display on the items matching these attributes, unfortunately I do not know how to do this.

I think I need to use Ajax for this but could be wrong and was wondering how I could set up my application so that it filters the results on the page. I am using Django 1.7 and python 2.7

Edit:

Apologies for being vague with my requirements, on my sites index page I have the items listed, each items has attributes such as category that I would like to filter by. I have not written any code for this part because I don't know how to get started with this and have, unfortunately, been unable to find anything online to help. I feel that there must be an easy way to update my index page to display only items that match the boxes checked and would be grateful for help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit vague in your question, but probably you are looking for something like [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) to automate filtering of lists.

Filters are defined in a similar way as you define Forms or Models, so its easy to learn. Example

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {'name': ['exact', 'icontains'],
                  'price': ['exact', 'gte', 'lte'],
                 }
```

No AJAX required.

But if you are using AJAX or D.R.F., there is an add-on for Django Filters, [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters), so it works well via REST with the D.R.F.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. So will this allow me to automatically update the page?